# Antd React : how to input a math formula on textfields

Tags: reactjs, antd

I was working on a project that serves different types of questions for a user.

```html
<form name="dynamic_form_nest_item"  hideRequiredMark form={form} onFinish={onfinish} autoComplete="off">
  <Form.Item name= 'Question' label="Question">
  <Input.TextArea />
  </Form.Item>
</form>
```

I came across some issues when I tried to input a mathematical Question. The `textfield` doesn't support derivations, integrations, power functions and degrees.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

There are some libraries that can convert a text to math equations. I suggest try to look on this one [react-mathjax2](https://github.com/wko27/react-mathjax).

Then make some binding so when you type on some `Input` you can also see the result math formula at the same time. Saved your text and use the library to render/display it.

See this example that I made:

[image: Edit prod-http-h73fi]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i wanted to capture the text or the equation written in the text field and send that data through an api endpoint. all formatted correctly before i send it. can react-mathjax2. provide this? if so how? Thanks

Comment: I think react-mathjax2 can only read a single line of text e.g. "c^2 = a^2 + b^2" and render it to browser as math equation.